# Highlight multiple Divs using JQuery and save pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to design a user friendly way of selecting multiple images and saving what was selected.

The page will contain 10 images each with their own unique id.

When a user selects an image, the containing div will highlight to show what is selected.

Have a working example here with a single click and not saving the selected divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/dtzjN/375/

My main issue is, when I click submit, I want to save the highlighted Divs to an array.

So if a user clicked on div id="image1" and div id="image3" and click submit,
these selected items would be added to an array, where I will then submit down.[image1,image3]

```
<div id="image1">Picture goes here</div>    
<div id="image2">Picture goes here</div>    
<div id="image3">Picture goes here</div>    
<div id="image4">Picture goes here</div>
```

I want to select multiple and add to an array.

```
var selectedDivs =[]
var addclass = 'color';
var $cols = $('.divs').click(function(e) {
    $cols.removeClass(addclass);
    $(this).addClass(addclass);
  <!--Add id of which divs are selected to selectedDivs -->
});
```

Comment: you forget to close " in div id's id="image2  use id="image2"

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve my problem .

Comment: share more code what have you tried only then others can help you

Comment: no one is going to write complete code for you. share your jQuery css etc

Comment: Do you want to allow multiple image selects, because you have shared a code which just selects one image at a time?

Comment: It is in the JFIddle i linked within my question, http://jsfiddle.net/dtzjN/375/

Comment: In the Fiddle there is only a single select. Do you want multiple selects?

Comment: Yes, I am having issue with multiple selects, and then adding the div id of what is selected to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use like this

- use with `toggleClass` instead of add and remove.Its help to check muliple image
- And after submit to match the each `.divs` with `hasClass('color')`.Then push with array

[**`Updated fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/dtzjN/379/)

```
var addclass = 'color';
 $('.divs').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass(addclass);
});

$(':submit').click(function(){
var res=[];
$('.divs').each(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('color')){
res.push($(this).attr('id'))
}

})
console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: Thanks @prasad, this works very well. The only thing is, that if I select an image, then click submit, then go back and select other images, The array still have the previously selected divs. Would a pop on deselecting a div, solve this?Or some possible way to ensure array always reflects divs selected upon submit.

Comment: @Blawless see the my answer . i was updated with fiddle.check this out

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for, Thank you .